# permissions checking in serializer, Django rest framework,

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions, django-serializer

I'm fairly new and django rest framework and  I have some questions regardin permissions.

So I have a user who is a member of organization and member of some group.
Lets say we have a model:

```
class SomeModel:
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    name = models.CharField()
```

User can only `create` / `update` `SomeModel` for its own organization and if he's a group of "Coordinators" he can also `create` / `update` for any organization.

Currently my approach is to check these conditions in serializer, in `.create()` and `.update()` methods, since the data is already validated and I'm raising `PermissionDenied` errors there. But it feels like that this is not "the right way". I tried making a custom permissions classes, but then the data is not validated, since permissions classes are checked before serializers.
Do you have any suggestions how should I approach this?

Sorry for bad english, it's not my native language.
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Example:
Request data is something like:

```
payload = {'organization': 1, 'name': 'Name'}
```

So if a user is from organization 1 or he's a coordinator access should be granted and `SomeModel` should be created

Comment: When using custom permission classes, why do you want to further validate data if a user does not have permission to create/update?

Comment: I need to check whether the organization in the model being created even exists.

Comment: I added an example, which may help understand my problem ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **write a custom permission class `HasWritePermissions`** which will check whether a user has write/update permissions.

To create a [custom permission class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions), you will need to override `BasePermission` class and implement `has_permission()` method. This method should return `True` if request is to granted access, otherwise `False`.

```
class HasWritePermissions(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # grant access to non-create/update requests
        if request.method not in ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH']:
            return True

        # grant access if user is a member of organization of the object 
        # to be modified or is a coordinator
        if (organization in user.organizations) or (user_is_a_coordinator):
            return True

        # Otherwise don't grant access
        return False
```

Comment: In order to check the object's organization, request data has to be validated first? Or how do I get object currently being created?

Comment: Yes, to handle both create/update using this method, you would have to perform lookup for organization object using its id and check that its in the user's organizations.

Comment: But what if organization field doesn't exists in request payload or organization id doesn't exist in database. That would cause some unwanted status 500 errors ... I could check all this things, but that is what serializer and validators are for?

Comment: You should do something like, `request.data.get('organization_id') in user_organizations_ids` list or maybe write a model method `is_organization_member(organization_id)` on `User` model for the same. You will pass `organization_id` value using `request.data.get()` which can be either `None` or some value. Then you can check if that value is in the list of user's  `organizations` ids. You won't have to worry about the `organization_id` field then if it exists or not or its a valid value or not.

Comment: Agreed, serializer should validate the data but as per the use case, request should not be granted access if a "valid"  `organization_id` is not in user's organizations ids list. Such requests should be stopped at permissions level. If the `organization_id` is invalid, you can let the request pass through and DRF serializer should return 400 errors.(yes, to some extent this includes some repetition.)

Comment: Where did you take 'user' object?